# Loosing the column name with getting a subset of a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm going to get a subset of my dataframe, but it's column name disappears. This is the code I use:

```
my_dataframe = df["column1"]
```

How can have the subset of df in my_dataframe without loosing the column name?

Comment: `df[["column1"]]`

Comment: You are getting series. So you might also do `my_dataframe.to_frame()`

Comment: Also, I'm worried about the fact that you're assigning this to something else. You'd end up getting a SettingWithCopy Warning down the road if you're not careful.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Tell me how you find the dupes.

Comment: @Dark When searching, use `site:stackoverflow.com` to streamline searches.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I didn't get your point about SettingWithCopy Warning. Could you elaborate it?

Comment: @woody Try this: `x = df[['b']]; x.loc[0, 'b'] = 1000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives a Series:

```
my_series = df["column1"]
```

but this a sub-dataframe:

```
my_dataframe = df[["column1"]]
```

which shows the column name.